# Chamando uma Activity dentro de um Fragment - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Preciso que a partir do click de um botão dentro do meu Fragment, ele chame uma Activity. Meu código está assim:

```java
public class ActFoto2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, 
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

    private Button proximo;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        String caminhoFoto = Util.getUltimaMidia(getActivity(), Util.MIDIA_FOTO);

        if (caminhoFoto != null) {
            mCaminhoFoto = new File(caminhoFoto);
        }

        proximo = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnProximo);

        proximo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActMapa.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Mas Mesmo assim ele não chama, e quando eu vou testar, ele para a aplicação. Alguém pode me auxiliar por favor. Valeu.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPt. Adicione a pilha de erros completa na pergunta. isto facilita o auxilio!

Comment: Você adicionou a tela no seu `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Se `proximo` é um botão da *activity* declare o `setOnClickListener()` lá, se não é o código está mal. Poste o *log* de erros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ActFoto2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

private Button proximo;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Define o XML do seu Fragment (o que contem o Button)
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.meulayout, parent, false);
}

// Qualquer alteração com o Layout XML e Java API deve ser feito aqui ex: Clicks etc.
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    proximo = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnProximo);

    proximo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActMapa.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}}
```

Isso resolve.

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado Alessandro, funcionou.

Comment: Fico feliz que funcionou, marque agora como a resposta certa

Answer (score -1):

Tente assim:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActMapa.class);
   getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```